# Manually manage child views in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, three.js

I am having difficulty finding the best way to manually manage a set of child views in Ember. I have a rough working example here: http://jsbin.com/ObIjosI/2/edit which is far from ideal since child view elements are inserted into the DOM then moved.

My use case is using Three.js CSS3D renderer to manipulate the position of Ember views' elements. The renderer has its own DOM element and structure independent from an Ember view or template.

I am searching for a solution that allows views' elements to be managed and rendered by Ember, but inserted and removed from the DOM with a Three.js CSS3D renderer.